# Rails routing - where does it go next?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have an html file as follows, located under `views/admin/ve_files/new.html.erb`

```
<div class="page-header">
    <h3>Hi</h3>
</div>
<%= simple_form_for @ve_file do |f| %>
<%= f.file_field :file %>
<br><br>
<%= f.submit "Upload" %>
<% end %>
<br>
```

And then I have a controller located under `controllers/admin/ve_files_controller.rb` which looks like so

```
require 'CSV'

class Admin::VeFilesController < ApplicationController

    layout 'admin'

    def new
        authorize! :create, :ve_file
        @ve_file = VeFile.new
    end

    def create
        puts "hello"
        authorize! :create, :ve_file
        #puts params
        @ve_file = VeFile.new(params[:ve_file])
        puts "okay"
        if @ve_file.save                
            CSV.foreach(@ve_file.file.path) do |row|
                puts row[0]
            end

            redirect_to admin_ve_path, :notice => 'Hi'
        else
            render :new
        end
    end
end
```

So when I click the Upload button in the html file, where does the program try to route me to? Where in the code is that specified? I get the following error and there is no output to the terminal:

```
Routing Error
uninitialized constant VeFilesController
```

because it should be `Admin::VeFilesController`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a namespace called `:admin`, so that needs to be specified in your call to `simple_form_for`.

You can do so like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for [:admin, @ve_file] do |f| %>
```

Comment: thanks! that fixed that problem. but now I get this error: 

NoMethodError in Admin::VeFilesController#create
undefined method `file_will_change!' for #<VeFile:0x007fa31a90a3c0>

Comment: Glad you got the routing to work! Sounds like another question needs to be asked. That is, after you try on your own for a little bit to figure out what's going on. :)